# How to fix "expecting member declaration" with recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created a `RecyclerView` but when I attempt to assign a `layoutManager` to the view I get the ubiquitous "Expecting member declaration". I am using `androidx`.

There seems to be a number of other problems with this error, but I can't align the solutions with my problem.

I have tried the `Build -> Clean` approach with no joy.
I have tried applying `lateinit` for the `recyclerview`

```
import android.content.Context
//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.room.Room


import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val DB_NAME = "Flt_Log.db"

    //lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    var recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_flightlist)

    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

...

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_flightlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        //tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="145dp"
        //tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="494dp"
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> error is against:     recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two mistakes in your code

You need to do **`findViewById`** inside `onCreate()` method

Use `recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)` inside `onCreate()` method

Also no need to do  `findViewById` you can use [`Kotlin Android Extensions`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)

Try this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val DB_NAME = "Flt_Log.db"

    //lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            var recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_flightlist)

    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: He is using kotlin synthetic properties, `findViewById` is not neccessary

Comment: Thanks Nilesh and @Daniel. Did the job. Still trying to get my head around all this.

Answer (score 1):

convert

```
val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_flightlist)
```

to

```
val recyclerView : RecylerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_flightlist)
```

You can also use [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) and just access recycler view directly because all of the heavy lifting is done for you.

```
rv_flightlist.layoutmanager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

Comment: first of all, avoid using var, it is a mistake, second thing is that the first variant is the most readable and the third should be avoided, that method is still available for backward compatibility.

Comment: Thanks @Mohan. Relying on the Kotlin Android Extension works - also needed to put the layoutmanager allocation into the onCreate